# how to save really long text in sql database

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

i am trying to make a meeting minutes website, in which the minutes of meeting are loged with respect to user, my problem is that minutes text can be very very long, larger then sql LONGTEXT datatype, how do i store such long text in a database? and if possible can that be exploded to array?

here is my code.

```
 <?php
   $subject = $location = $date = $starttime = $endtime = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {   
           $subject = $_POST["subject"]; 
           $location = $_POST["location"];
           $date = $_POST["date"];
           $starttime = $_POST["starttime"];
           $endtime = $_POST["endtime"];
           $email = $_POST["email"];
           $orignal_minutes = $_POST["Oriminutes"];
           $edited_minutes = $_POST["Ediminutes"];
           }


          if($_POST['submit'] != "" )
          {      
         $tablename = "WM_".$subject;     

        $createTable = "CREATE TABLE `$tablename`(
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT KEY, 
        subject VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, location VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
        starttime VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, endtime VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        minutes VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL )";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $createTable)){
        echo "Table `$tablename` created successfully";}
        else{ echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn); }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tablename` (id, subject, date, location, starttime, endtime, email, minutes )
                VALUES (DEFAULT,'$subject','$date','$location', '$starttime' ,'$endtime', '$email','$orignal_minutes')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);



          }
```

Comment: if i enter really long text, the table is created but there are no rows!

Comment: you can use datatype `nvarchar(max)` and `text` in SQL SERVER

Comment: you are dealing with SQL-Server or mysql? you have both in the tags (mysqli -> mysql) they have different data types and the proper answer depends on the RDBMS you use.

Comment: @tinka don't use `text` on sql server. it's deprecated and will be removed in future versions. `varchar(max)` is recommended instead of `text` since sql server 2008, or even before..

Comment: thanks for share valuable info @ZoharPeled

Comment: Clean the variables you are inserting to DB, your variables may contain single qoutes and it will ruin the query.

Comment: @Paolo this is not tsql syntax. note the `auto_increment` - that's mysql, not sql server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled agreed. so there was a wrong tag.

Comment: @Paolo hence my edit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to save a very long text, consider saving that text to a txt file or something, and then just save the file name/path into DB.

If you want to display it, just use the DB as reference to the file and get it.

Comment: how to save the filename path? and should i save the file on the same server?

Comment: Using php fopen, here's a reference http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: should i save the file on the same server - Yes preferably

Answer (score 0):

If you have texts longer than the Maximum of varchar, you should use clobs (character large objects). They exist for most (if not all) database types.